# BigCommerce Stencil - GraphQL query using front matter not returning anything

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm not sure if it's a bug, but I'm not able to make GraphQL work in the Cornerstone template. I'm expecting an error or something getting returned at least, but nothing is being rendered at all from `gql`.

I am on the `pages/product.html` template, and I even tried this example from the [docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/front-matter-reference):

```yaml
---
product:
   videos:
       limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_videos_count}}
   reviews:
       limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_reviews_count}}
   related_products:
       limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_related_products_count}}
   similar_by_views:
       limit: {{theme_settings.productpage_similar_by_views_count}}
gql: "query productById($productId: Int!) {
 site {
   product(entityId: $productId) {
     variants(first: 25) {
       edges {
         node {
           sku
           defaultImage {
             url(width: 1000)
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
 "
```

My goal is to have access to the paths/URL on each of the product's category because `product.category` is just an array of category names. Here's the query I am able to make work on the GraphQL playground (`86` to be replaced by `$productId` in the front matter GraphQL query, I think?):

```
query getProductCategories {
  site {
    product(entityId: 86) {
      categories {
        edges {
          node {
            name
            path
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If there's no way around this, maybe I'll just try to do the fetching in the client side.

Comment: There's a bug at the moment where the GQL results do not work when viewing the theme locally in stencil-cli, but they work when you upload the theme. The CLI bug is being fixed soon.

Answer (score 2):

This now works correctly, as of 20-Sep-2021.

There was a bug, tracked as an issue here: https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/issues/732 which has been resolved and closed.